# How to set priority for test methods execution using Annotation?

Tags: java

How to set priority for test methods execution using Annotation?

Got annotation with priority:

```
@Retention(RetentionPolicy.RUNTIME)
@Target(ElementType.METHOD)
public @interface Test {
    int priority();
}
```

Got test class:

```
  @Test(priority = 9)
    public static void test(){
        System.out.println("Test9");
    }

    @Test(priority = 8)
    public static void test1(){
        System.out.println("Test8");
    }

    @Test(priority = 7)
    public static void test2(){
        System.out.println("Test7");
    }
}
```

Got method to execute with priority, but it's not working:

```
for (Method m : methods){
        if (m.isAnnotationPresent(Test.class) && m.getAnnotation(Test.class).priority() == 9){
            m.invoke(null);
        }
        if (m.isAnnotationPresent(Test.class) && m.getAnnotation(Test.class).priority() == 8){
            m.invoke(null);
        }
        if (m.isAnnotationPresent(Test.class) && m.getAnnotation(Test.class).priority() == 7){
            m.invoke(null);
        }
    }
```

How to execute methods with priority?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I guess, you are using junit library for testing. You can use `@Order` annotation

```
@Test
@Order(1)    
public void firstTest() {
    output.append("a");
}

@Test
@Order(2)    
public void secondTest() {
    output.append("b");
}
```

or in this documentation there are different ways to do this.

https://www.baeldung.com/junit-5-test-order